# How to get the exact frame rate with metal?

Tags: ios, xcode, metal, metalkit

I made a framework that is easily switchable between **OpenGL** and **Metal**. I notice that when I'm on **OpenGL** the animations are smoother than on **Metal**. Under **Metal** I look at with rate the `drawInMTKView` is called and it's exactly at **60 fps**. it's taken me exactly **8 ms** (in average) to do everything in the `drawInMTKView` (so end by `commandBuffer.commit`), that it's much less than **16 ms**. So seam that there is some jobs in the GPU, outside of the `drawInMTKView`, that I don't see and that make the animation not working at exactly **60 fps**. How to measure exactly the frame rate of my app? what can explain that my animations are not smoother than on **OpenGL** when `drawInMTKView` is called exactly every **16 ms**?

Note: I'm not under Xcode but under a multi platform development tool

Comment: First, are you sure the Metal validation layer is not enabled when you're running the Metal renderer? Second, the best tool for investigating Metal performance is Instruments with the Game Performance template. See [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/606/). Also, even though you're not using Xcode for primary development, you may want to **run** your app under it for its GPU Frame Debugger, which can highlight performance issues and recommend fixes.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 what is FPS counter ?

Comment: and how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use custom **FPS** counter.

**FPS.hpp:**

```
#ifndef FPS_hpp
#define FPS_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

class FPS
{
public:
    FPS(float interval);
    void getFPS(double time, float *out);
};

#endif /* FPS_hpp */
```

**FPS.cpp:**

```
#include "FPS.hpp"

float UpdateInterval = 0.5f;
float accum = 0.0f;
int frames = 0;
float timeLeft;

FPS::FPS(float interval)
{
    UpdateInterval = interval;
    timeLeft = UpdateInterval;
}

double previousTime;
void FPS::getFPS(double time, float *out)
{
    float deltaTime = time - previousTime;
    previousTime = time;

    timeLeft -= deltaTime;
    accum += 1 / deltaTime;
    ++frames;

    if(timeLeft <= 0.0)
    {
        float fps = accum/frames;
        *out = fps;

        timeLeft = UpdateInterval;
        accum = 0;
        frames = 0;
     }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
#import "FPS.hpp"
FPS *fps;


void init()
{
   fps = new FPS(0.3f);
}


[commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer)
 {
        float fpsa = 0;
        fps->getFPS(buffer.GPUEndTime, &fpsa);
        if(fpsa != 0) NSLog(@"%f", fpsa);
}];
```